Create 48 month array of summed arrays offset and multiplied for each month
I've hunted around and know the answer will be in here somewhere, but where?
I have a 48 month revenue profile and would like to multiply it by the number of such customers won in each of 48 months offset without creating a 48 row waterfall.
Essentially, summing a set of arrays:

1 2 3 ... 47 48 all x customers month 1
0 1 2 ... 46 47 all x customers month 2
0 0 1 ... 45 46 all x customers month 3
...
0 0 0 ... 00 01 all x customers month 48

The individual 48 month arrays offset a column at a time are created by the following:
=HSTACK(SEQUENCE(1,E$3,0,0),OFFSET($E23,0,0,1,49-E$3)*E$37)


E3# is the month number from 1 to 48,
E23# is the 48 month array and
E37# is the 48 multipliers.

The offset shifts the revenue profile out a month each time. The array is increased to 49 with HSTACK for consistency; otherwise when summing the rows I get an error in the final cells. SEQUENCE adds at least a column.
Thank you in advance!
I can create 48 of these rows and add them (eg E40#+E41#+E42#+ etc), but would like to do so on a single row (because I've got to do this multiple times for multiple customer types). I've tried various LAMBDA functions, but just get #CALC!
